# The element type 'Question' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'

Tags: flutter, dart, constructor, widget

I can't use my own `Class/Widget Question()` from `question.dart` to `main.dart` (ERR Location 3rd line after body):

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './question.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    // TODO: implement createState
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var questionIndex = 0;
  // State of function that process data to UI
  void _answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      questionIndex = questionIndex + 1;
    });
    print(questionIndex);
  }

  void _pangBawas() {
    setState(() {
      questionIndex = questionIndex - 1;
    });
    print(questionIndex);
  }

  // End of State
  // This section is responsible for builing UI
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = [
      'What\'s your favorite color?',
      'What\'s your favorite animal?',
      'What\'s your favorite food?',
      'What\'s your favorite color?',
      'What\'s your favorite dress?',
      'What\'s your favorite position?',
    ];
    // Start of UI
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Question( //ERROR: The element type 'Question' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.
              questions[questionIndex],
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Answer 1'),
              onPressed: _answerQuestion,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Answer 2'),
              onPressed: () => _pangBawas,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Answer 3'),
                onPressed: () {
                  //....
                  print('Hi');
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    // End of UI
  }
}
```

There's no error here, I only get error using `Question()` on my `main.dart` file

```dart
import 'package:/flutter/material.dart';

class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  final String questionText;

  Question(this.questionText);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Text(
        questionText,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making use of interpolation solves some errors and displays the error to you in your UI. The code below works just fine:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Question extends StatelessWidget {
  final String questiontext;
  Question(this.questiontext);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text("$questiontext");
  }
}

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var questionIndex = 0;
  // State of function that process data to UI
  void _answerQuestion() {
    setState(() {
      questionIndex = questionIndex + 1;
    });
    print(questionIndex);
  }

  void _pangBawas() {
    setState(() {
      questionIndex = questionIndex - 1;
    });
    print(questionIndex);
  }

  // End of State
  // This section is responsible for builing UI
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var questions = [
      'What\'s your favorite color?',
      'What\'s your favorite animal?',
      'What\'s your favorite food?',
      'What\'s your favorite color?',
      'What\'s your favorite dress?',
      'What\'s your favorite position?',
    ];
    // Start of UI
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('My First App'),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Question(
              //ERROR: The element type 'Question' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.
              "${questions[questionIndex]}",
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Answer 1'),
              onPressed: _answerQuestion,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('Answer 2'),
              onPressed: () => _pangBawas,
            ),
            RaisedButton(
                child: Text('Answer 3'),
                onPressed: () {
                  //....
                  print('Hi');
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
    // End of UI
  }
}
```

[image: output here]

Answer (score 0):

You could add itinerary operator to check If the Widget that is returned from the Question class is null or not. This happens because the Column's children widgets can't be null.

```
 body: Column(
      children: [
        Question(questions[questionIndex]) == null
            ? SizedBox()
            : Question(questions[questionIndex]),
```

This way if the widget returned from the Question class is null, then the Column will create a SizedBox instead of the Container + Text.